# How to run apache nutch in distributed mode

Tags: hadoop, web-crawler, nutch

I am using Apache Nutch 2.3. I have a small cluster of 4 Hadoop (1.2.1) nodes. I am running one instance of the Crawler. It crawls about 30k-50k pages per day. I have to crawl more pages per day (supposed value is about 1 million). I have tried different questions from FAQ of Nutch. But documents crawled could not increased. I think I should run Nutch in fully distributed mode (I expect full distributed mode of Nutch is running more than one instance).

What is the solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should increase topN value and set the value of `<name>http.content.limit</name>` (in nutch-site.xml) to **-1**